# How to display partial values of JSON Encode values

Tags: json

I want to display partial values of JSON Encode values. Following is the code.

```
<?php global $wpdb; $project_member_details = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT project_members FROM wpxa_project_members WHERE project_id = 603" ) ); echo $project_member_details; ?>
```

I get following result...

```
{"member_image":["21604_1530889966_1408904487.png","21604_1530889966_1590217155.jpg","21604_1530889966_1179667677.png"],"member_name":["Test","Best","Guest"],"member_role":["Test1","Best1","Guest1"],"member_email":["Test2@bas.com","Best2@bas.com","Guest2@fdd.com"],"member_facebook_id":["Test3","Best3","Guest3"]}
```

But I want only this... How to do...

```
{"member_image":["21604_1530889966_1408904487.png","21604_1530889966_1590217155.jpg","21604_1530889966_1179667677.png"]
```

Plz help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
global $wpdb;
$project_member_details = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT project_members FROM wpxa_orocox_project_members WHERE project_id = 603" ) );
$project_member_details = json_decode( $project_member_details, true );
print_r( $project_member_details['member_image'] );
```

If you still want the output to be JSON encoded at the end of it, you could then do something like:

```
$member_images = $project_member_details['member_image'];
echo wp_json_encode( [ 'member_image' => $member_images ] );
```